# How do I increase performance of a table in Oracle11g which acts as a queue

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

We have a table I'll call it Foo. This table gets 100 records inserted per user. We expect a given user to hit his or her records heavily for an hour or two, then periodically for 1-3 days, then rarely/never for 90 days, and then the records are deleted (at the 90 day mark). Some records will not be deleted at the 90 day mark, but likely will only very rarely be accessed. Our current table size is ~20 million records.

Should we use any sort of fancy index on this table? (ie reverse key index, parallel index)

Should we schedule rebuilding or coalescing of the indexes on this table due to the deletions?

Should we be partitioning this table?

Is there anything else that should be done to help performance?

Comment: This question is probably more appropriate for dba.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

Why pull all kinds of rabbits out of a hat and index data you would never use, why not instead of facing these problems arrange the data to stay in a less volatile environment. Move your old data or unchanging data to a table that is not used (create table as is your friend with big amounts of data).